# Changing forecolor and backcolor of text using GDI+ Graphics methods - Convert colors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, gdi

i have a richtextbox and i want to make black color that text has to blue and the background color from white to yellow.

I do not want to do .SelectionColor=Color.Blue or .SelectionBackColor=Color.Yellow but instead i want to do that using the gdi+ FillRectangle methods or somehow else.

I have the text with a white background and i want to make the background color to yellow and the forecolor from black to blue.

Is there such a way to do that such as FillRectangle. I tried to do a FillRectangle with a transparent color but the colors werent't great afterwards.

In general in GDI+ how can i convert two colors from one to antoher ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this

```
        Graphics g = ((Control)richTextBox1).CreateGraphics();
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Comment: i know how to draw a filled Rectangle.

The problem is that the RichTextBox is already painted. I want to converted the painted colors to something else. 

I paint with a semi transparent Brush but the colors are pale.

Comment: And can you describe me this "how can i convert two colors from one to another", show me example